# Access last two digits of hex number in MIPS

Tags: assembly, hex, mips, bitwise-operators

I want to print out the last two digits of a hexadecimal number in MIPS.  I have this code but the output is 0x00000000 when I expected the output to be 0x00000021.  Where am I going wrong?

```
.data
num:  .word 0x00654321
.text
la $s0, num # make s0 equal to num
andi $a0, $s0, 0x00000011 # do bitwise AND
li $v0 34 # print result in hex
syscall
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`la $s0, num` gives you the address of `num`, not the value stored there. The instruction you want is `lw`.

And when you mask you should use `0xFF` to get the two least significant hex digits, not `0x11`. Using `0x11` would only give you the least significant bit of those digits, e.g. `0x21 & 0x11` = `0x01`.